# What does this function do? I understand the recursion aspect but am confused with the following operations

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, nodes

```
class Node{
 public:
 int data;
 Node* next;
};
int func(Node* node, int number){
  if(node){ //whilst the node does not equal null pointer
    if(node->data > 0) // if the data is greater than 0 
      return func(node->next, number) - node->data; // this is where i get confused...
    else if(node->data < 0)
      return func(node->next, number) + node->data;
    else
      return func(node->next, number + node->data) + number;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I see that it does a recursive call to the function to use the following node in the sequence, then it subtracts the child nodes data from the parent node? Is my understanding thus far correct? What is the function trying to achieve? In my mind I was thinking the function is trying to set the data of all nodes in the linked list to 0? Would that be a correct assumption.

Comment: You could (should) step-wise debug the code with a small sample to understand what it does.

Comment: Concerning _then it subtracts the child nodes data from the parent node?_ It subtracts the child nodes data from the result (return value) of the recursive call of `func()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> subtracts the child nodes data from the parent node

No, it subtracts `node->data` from the *result* of the recursive call.

> What is the function trying to achieve?

Ask the author. What we can tell you is what it *does* achieve. I am suspicious of the author's understanding of this function because `number + node->data` appears where `node->data` is known to be 0.

The first two conditions are the same as subtracting the absolute value of each `node->data`, and the last condition adds `number` every time there is a 0.

Comment: I am confused on what you mean by  "subtracting the absolute value of each `node->data`". Is the function subtracting the value until the data is 0?

Comment: [Absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) is a mathematical operation, it discards the sign of a number. Adding a negative value is equivalent to subtracting a positive value of the same magnitude

Comment: Is the number different from the data of the node?

Comment: `number` is a parameter to the function. It is passed (unchanged) to all the recursive calls

Comment: That makes sense. It doesn't affect the result of the recursive calls then right? Sorry I am still a bit confused. If `node->data` is greater than 0 than it does a recursive call on the child of that node which it then subtracts from the original node. What does that do exactly though? You mentioned absolute value, does that mean the function give us the absolute value of the data in each node?

Comment: There is always a `func(node->next, number)` call (`number + 0` in one case). Then we either subtract positive `data`, add negative `data` or add `number` for zero data.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. That makes a lot more sense to me now. Just to reiterate, that means that the function makes the data of node passed to equal zero?

Comment: No, it does not modify any of the nodes. It calculates a value based on the nodes and `number`

Comment: If the function calculates a value based on the node and a number, is that referring to the absolute value you were mentioning earlier?

Comment: `int value = node->data ? -std::abs(node->data) : number; return func(node->next, number) + value;` would be equivalent, yes